# How to improve the sidenav animation performance angular material

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have made a sidenav using angular-material's md-sidenav and below is the screenshot of it. When i try click on the button for sidenav the animations pretty lagging. I have used on an image on the top bar and the rest just text with font-awesome icons. What could i be possibly doing bad that it is slow. The animations are even worse when i view it on mobile.

Screenshot of sidenav :

[image: sidenav]

Here is the code of sidenav :

```
<md-sidenav class="boxme-sidenav" layout="column" hide-gt-sm class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left">
    <div layout="coloumn" style="z-index:1000;box-shadow:2px 0px 10px grey;">
        <div flex class="sidenav-logo">
            <img ng-src="{{mainLogo}}" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <md-list style="background-color:#00B0FF;color:white;z-index:10;">
        <md-list-item class="md-2-line sidenav-list" layout-padding>
            <md-button href="" layout-align="space-around center">
            <i class="fa fa-size fa-briefcase"></i>
              <span class="md-body-2">Dashboard</span>
            </md-button>
        </md-list-item>
        <md-list-item class="md-2-line sidenav-list" layout-padding layout-align="start center">
            <md-button href="">
              <i class="fa fa-size fa-user"></i>
              <span>My Stuff</span>
            </md-button>
        </md-list-item>
        <md-list-item class="md-2-line sidenav-list" layout-padding layout-align="start center">
            <md-button href="">
              <i class="fa fa-size fa-file-o"></i>
              <span>Order History</span>
            </md-button>
        </md-list-item>
        <md-list-item class="md-2-line sidenav-list" layout-padding layout-align="start center">
            <md-button href="">
              <i class="fa fa-size fa-credit-card"></i>
              <span>Billing</span>
            </md-button>
        </md-list-item>
        <md-divider></md-divider>
        <md-subheader style="background-color:#00B0FF;color:white;">Manage the items</md-subheader><!--You can use md-no-sticky class-->
        <md-list-item class="md-2-line sidenav-list" layout-padding layout-align="start center">
          <md-button href=""><i class="fa fa-size fa-user"></i> Pickup my stuff</md-button>
        </md-list-item>
        <md-list-item class="md-2-line sidenav-list" layout-padding layout-align="start center">
          <md-button href=""><i class="fa fa-size fa-user"></i> Deliver my stuff</md-button>
        </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</md-sidenav>
```

Note :

After a while the performance and animations of sidenav get real lagging on the web.

Comment: Doesit goes fast without the images? If yes, you should compress them and use Sprites

Comment: @gr3g there is not much considerable performance improvement

Comment: Can you post the animation code / css?

Comment: @OriDrori the code is simple $mdSidenav('left').toggle(), the default angular-material animation and no extra additions

Comment: I am experiencing this issue as well, it was working fine in the beginning but it gradually slowed down as webapp became more complex - must be the way animation is handled as manually adding css transition and changing transform property is fast as it should be (changing content in sidebar or in 'page' has no effect for me).

Answer (score 10):

It may not be right solution for your case, but disabling backdrop and adding 1 tweak made transition performance acceptable for me (even on phone)

```
.md-sidenav-backdrop {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}

md-sidenav.md-closed-add,
md-sidenav.md-closed-remove {
    -webkit-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.25, .8, .25, 1) !important;
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.25, .8, .25, 1) !important;
}
```

Comment: Just dropped this in seems to work pretty well thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

I decided to just remove the animation as follows:

I looked through the AngularMaterial CSS file and removed all references to animations. KA-BOOM!

```
/**
* fix md-sidenav lag by removing animation
**/

.md-sidenav-backdrop {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}

md-sidenav.md-closed-add,
md-sidenav.md-closed-remove,
md-sidenav.md-closed-add.md-closed-add-active, 
md-sidenav.md-closed-remove.md-closed-remove-active,
md-sidenav.md-locked-open-remove-active,
md-sidenav.md-closed.md-locked-open-add-active

{
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```

---- edit ----

Also update to the latest version of AngularMaterial there seems to be an overall improvement in v1.0.0-rc4 compared to prior releases.